# Bool function call, what does this notation mean?

Tags: java

Its a kinda newbish question, hope you guys dont mind and can explain this to me.

this function call:

```
System.out.println(doStuff(a)?"YES":"NO");
```

I've never used this notation before, what does the "?" mean in this function?
Its a call to bool function, i guess whenever it returns false it print "NO",and when true prints "YES" ?
I'm kinda used to this kinda way to write em

```
if(doStuff(a)==true) {
System.out.println("YES");
}
```

Can someone maybe point me to a resource where i can read more about this alternative way to write those boolean function calls? I've havent been able to find anything.

Comment: You can read about ternary operator in java.

Comment: It is called [the conditional operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html).

Comment: Thanks, reading up on it now!

Comment: By the way, you would never need to write `something == true`. It is equivalent to simply writing `something`. Similarly, writing `something == false` is equivalent to writing `!something`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional *expression*:

```
boolCondition ? "YES" : "NO"
```

It works when the condition, which may be any `boolean` expression, is used to choose between *two values of the same type*. Type limitation is critical: both sides of the colon `:` must produce objects or values of the same type.

In your case the expression controlling the conditional is a call is a call of a method returning `boolean`, which controls the choice between two objects of type `String`.

This is a conditional *statement*:

```
if (boolCondition) {
    ... // Statements A
} else {
    ... // Statements B
}
```

Statement does not have the same limitation as the expression, in that the two blocks of executable statements controlled by the condition can do entirely unrelated things.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ternary operator.
The sintax is condition ? 
true evaluation> : false evaluation

```
1==1 ? "True" : "false"
```